# Program to read values from USB in linux

Tags: usb, hardware

So, I need to read data coming in from the USB port. Normally I do this with Realterm when I am on a Windows computer. But now I am on a linux computer and would like to do the same thing. What is a good replacement?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use libusb - see http://www.libusb.org/

It comes with lots of functions/source/samples for USB and allows reading/writing etc.

It is licensed under LGPL 2.1

Answer (score 0):

[realterm](http://realterm.sourceforge.net/) is a windows terminal emulator. [Here is the](https://superuser.com/questions/80506/what-is-the-best-linux-terminal-emulator) [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) thread that got closed on the same subject.